# Binding routes when using an app factory

Tags: python, flask

How are routes suppose to be handled in flask when using an app factory? Given a package `blog` that contains everything needed for the app and a management script that creates the app then how are you suppose to reference the app in the routes?

```
├── blog
    ├── manage.py 
    └── blog
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── config.py  
        └── routes.py
```

**manage.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from flask.ext.script import Manager

manager = Manager(create_app)

# <manager commands>
# ...
# ...

manager.add_option('-c', '--config', dest='config', required=False)
manager.run()
```

**blog/__init__.py**

```
from flask import flask
from .config import Default

def create_app(config=None):

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Default)

    if config is not None:
        app.config.from_pyfile(config)

    return app
```

**blog/routes.py**

```
@app.route()  # <-- erm, this won't work now!? 
def index():
     return "Hello"
```

The problem is the app is created outside the package so how are the routes suppose to be handled with a setup like this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Usually I use application factories with blueprint.

`blog/__init__.py`

```
from flask import flask
from .config import Default

def create_app(config=None):

    app = Flask(__name__)
    if config is not None:
        app.config.from_pyfile(config)
    else:
        app.config.from_object(Default)

    from blog.routes import route_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(route_blueprint)

    return app
```

`blog/routes.py`

```
from flask import Blueprint
route_blueprint = Blueprint('route_blueprint', __name__)

@route_blueprint.route()
def index():
     return "Hello"
```

---

[docs: Application Factories](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/appfactories/)